# Using a remote repository with non-standard port

Tags: git

I am setting up my local git project for a remote repository. The remote repository is being served on a non-standard port (4019).

But it doesn't work. Instead I get the following error message:

```
ssh: connect to host git.host.de:4019 port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push to 'ssh://root@git.host.de:4019/var/cache/git/project.git'
```

My local git config is [as follows](http://pastie.org/652605):

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
  url = ssh://root@git.host.de:4019/var/cache/git/project.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

(The port and host are placeholders for the actual port and host.)

What is wrong with my git configuration?

Comment: Looks like if you don't explicitly put `ssh://` in front of the url, it thinks it's a different format.  so `ssh://example.com:444/etc/` is /etc/ on example.com via port 44.  Whereas `example.com:444/etc/` is /444/etc/ on example.com via port 22.

Comment: @Kzqai  remark is important. i.e if you do `git remote set-url origin git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/yourname/yourrepo/` it wont work. but, if you do `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/yourname/yourrepo/` this will work

Comment: For the Google-fu - I had this problem with phabricator when i had it set to a non-default port of 2222. Now, sorted!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

If you put something like this in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host githost
HostName git.host.de
Port 4019
User root
```

then you should be able to use the basic syntax:

```
git push githost:/var/cache/git/project.git master
```

Comment: A SSH config might be a workaround, but this got me interested, because man git-push says that the accepted ssh url format is ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/

Comment: I'm not sure, it may be a configuration git/ssh version issue because I tried to push to a ssh://fake@localhost:333/fake address and got (as expected) "port 333: Connection refused".

Comment: Attention anyone who still needs this. The syntax is `git clone ssh://username@hostname:333/~/repo` for a path relative to your home directory or `git clone ssh://username@hostname:333/path/to/repo` for an absolute path

Comment: on a windows machine: c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts to set a host name if needed (e.g. virtual machines / servers)

Comment: How can this be done if I have an IP and not a host name? I ask because we haven't linked our host name to our ip yet.

Comment: In ubuntu, use `sudo nano ~/.ssh/config` to edit the config file.

Answer (score 148):

SSH based git access method can be specified in `<repo_path>/.git/config` using either a full URL or an SCP-like syntax, as specified in http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone:

URL style:

```
url = ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

SCP style:

```
url = [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/
```

Notice that the SCP style does not allow a direct port change, relying instead on an `ssh_config` host definition in your `~/.ssh/config` such as:

```
Host my_git_host
HostName git.some.host.org
Port 24589
User not_a_root_user
```

Then you can test in a shell with:

```
ssh my_git_host
```

and alter your SCP-style URI in `<repo_path>/.git/config` as:

```
url = my_git_host:path/to/repo.git/
```

Comment: Soooooo... all that's really needed is adding a ssh:// in front of the url, probably.

Comment: Didn't realize you could specify ssh urls or that scp (the default) didn't allow port numbers.  Good to know.

Comment: scp actually allows port number (but the option key must be capital P): `scp -P 2020 file/to/copy user@host:path/to/copy/file/to`

Comment: For me it was enough to add `ssh://` to my `url`. If protocol is missing then git uses default port: `22`. Thank you.

Comment: In ubuntu, use `sudo nano ~/.ssh/config` to edit the config file.

Answer (score 31):

Try this

```
git clone ssh://user@32.242.111.21:11111/home/git/repo.git
```

Comment: Hi Ricky , it has worked for me with the syntax git clone ssh://user@machine:port/path-to-repo , where you write machine must be user, thanks

Answer (score 9):

This avoids your problem rather than fixing it directly, but I'd recommend adding a `~/.ssh/config` file and having something like this

```
Host git_host
HostName git.host.de
User root
Port 4019
```

then you can have

```
url = git_host:/var/cache/git/project.git
```

and you can also `ssh git_host` and `scp git_host ...` and everything will work out.

Answer (score 8):

SSH doesn't use the `:` syntax when specifying a port. The easiest way to do this is to edit your `~/.ssh/config` file and add:

```
Host git.host.de
  Port 4019
```

Then specify just `git.host.de` without a port number.