# Git: move existing repository from PC to server, clone from server

Tags: git, version-control, command-line, repository

I have an existing Git repository on my local machine.  I would like to move that repository to my web server, then `git clone` on my local machine to check out my repository from the server.  I'm planning on then developing on my local machine and pushing updates back to the server.  I can ssh from my local machine to the server, but not vice versa.  How should I go about this?  I think [git bundle](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) should be used somehow, though when I tried to `git clone` my bundle on my server, I got a "warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout" error.  My local machine is running OS X, the server is running Linux.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On the Linux server, in a new directory do:

```
git init --shared --bare
```

Then on your local machine:

```
git remote add origin server:path/to/repo
git push --all origin
```

After that, the server will have a full copy of the repository, and you will be able to push and pull to and from it. There's no need to check out another clone from the server when you've already got one locally.

Comment: Upon doing `git push origin master`, I get a long error that starts with "Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository".  The only contents of my repos on the Linux server is ".  ..  .git  HEAD  branches  config  description  hooks  info  objects  refs", which is what the `git init --shared --bare` command created.  I'm using git 1.7.1.1 on both computers.

Comment: Whoop, never mind!  I got it to work just now.  I hadn't actually created a new directory on the Linux server, I had just removed what I thought were all of its contents before running the `git init...` command.  Creating a new directory, `git init...`ing it, changing to use that origin from my local repos, and then pushing worked.

Comment: This works fine in principle, but I needed a few extra steps to make it work, because my server runs a non-standard ssh port: on OS X. I started by installing ssh-askpass (https://github.com/markcarver/mac-ssh-askpass), then I had to configure the port in ~/.ssh/config (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5738592/217953), using the SCP-style URL.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of "git push origin master" use "git push --all origin" so that you move over all branches and not just the master branch.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
local> cd my_repo.git
local> git remote add origin user@host:/path/to/my_repo.git
local> git config branch.master.remote origin
local> git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
local> git push origin master
```

That will send the data from your local repo to your server.  Then do this:

```
local> cd ..
local> git clone user@host:/path/to/my_repo.git my_repo2.git
```

Then you will have cloned from the server.  When satisfied, you can get rid of the original repo, and possibly rename the second one.