# Git "does not appear to be a git repository" ip and port instead of domain?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to commit my first Git repository to a gitlab instance, which I've set up on a debian-VM. Everything is going to happen via local network. The following commands are shown in gitlab after creating a new repo.

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@10.200.3.248:1337:Matt/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

After entering `git push -u origin master` this happens:

```
git@10.200.3.248's password:
fatal: '1337:Matt/test.git' does not appear to be a Git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Could the problem be the port on which Git is running at? Gitlab is accessible through port 617 so I'am able to reach the GUI via http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:617/Matt/test

The password I've entered seems to be correct, because a wrong password will end up in a "permission denied" message. OT: I don't know why I've to enter a passwd, because I've generated and added ssh-keys, as described in gitlab, but that's an other problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've solved my problem. The given port 1337 wasn't the problem, although it was wrong too, because ssh does not seem to be able to handle a port in url:

[Using a remote repository with non-standard port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558719/using-a-remote-repository-with-non-standard-port)

The Git-url which worked for me was:

```
git@10.200.3.248:repositories/Matt/test.git
```

My Git user home dir is located in `/home/git/` and the repositories are stored in `/home/git/repositories` so i had to add repositories to my Git-path.

The reason why GitLab told me to use the url `git@10.200.3.248:1337:Matt/test.git` seems to be a wrong configured Git path in GitLab. I'll try to fix this now.

Edit:

The wrong host was configured in `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml`. The "host" there must be without port... There is an extra option for the port if needed.

Edit3:
Still unable to push or fetch my test-repository without `repositories` in path..
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#could-not-read-from-remote-repository

Maybe something to do with rsa-keys but I don't understand how this belongs together.

**Edit4: (Problem(s) seem to be solved)**
My rsa-keys were ok. The problem was that I've configured my sshd_config to allow only a certain user for ssh-login. I've simply added Git to the list of allowed users `AllowUsers mylogin git`

Now I don't have to login via password anymore (You never have to login via password if ssh rsa keys are set up correctly) and the path works without "repositories" as it should. Now I understand, that this is just a normal ssh-connection - I hadn't realized this before..

The way I figured it out:

login via terminal as root:

```
service ssh stop #Current SSH-Connection won't be closed..
/usr/sbin/sshd -d

====debugging mode===
```

Then in Git Bash:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.example.com
```

Afterwards the terminal with sshd running in debug mode has thrown an error that Git is not allowed to login because of AllowUsers...

Don't forget to start your ssh service afterwards:

```
service ssh start
```

Comment: I am not sure you should ever have to specify the local path of `Matt/test.git`: '`repositories`' shouldn't ever be mentioned here.

Comment: You are right: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#could-not-read-from-remote-repository But I'm still unable to get that working. Still trying.. this time on a completely fresh debian wheezy.

Comment: Now that look like a valid resolution. +1

Comment: adding `repositories/`did it also for me

Answer (score -4):

use this format:

`git remote add origin ssh://git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337/Matt/test.git`

`user@host:[port]/path`
in most cases, we omit the port and it looks like this: `user@host:/path` ....

Comment: TY! I've also tried this. Actually the error-message I've posted is from this url-setup fatal: '1337/Matt/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: forgot you didn't specific a protocal
try this 
git remote add origin ssh://git@10.200.3.248:1337/Matt/test.git