# How to update git's remote address/port in local machine

Tags: git, push

In my company, whenever I want to push to `git server` from within the company, I have no problem as the .git/config file is like:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = me@172.x.x.x:/home/git/repositories/YYY
```

our company has a public IP and they say the access to our `git server` is from :

```
137.a.a.a:bbb
```

I need to push to the remote branch from home, but I dont know how to configure the git using this IP, I tried to change the above url to

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = me@137.a.a.a:bbb/home/git/repositories/YYY
```

but there was no luck.the error says:

```
ssh: connect to host 137.a.a.a port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

There problem could be a firewall or other networking issue. But before that, I want to make sure if my change is correct or not.
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing your existing remote, I suggest adding a new one. In the end they will point to the same server, but I personally prefer to use local IPs when possible.
To add a new remote, you simply execute `git remote add <name> <Address>`
You can then access the remote like origin, just replace any occurrence of `origin` with your new name.

This will not fix your problem, however. The problem seems to be that you don't get a connection.
My guess is, that you are trying to use a port, but use wrong syntax, try this:
`url = ssh://me@137.a.a.a:bbb/home/git/repositories/YYY`
This turns it into a real url, the way you did it before does accept ports afaik.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558719/using-a-remote-repository-with-non-standard-port)

Comment: I created another remote, and then followed the second step. This time it was able to connect and ask for password but it then says: `fatal: '/home/git/repositories/YYY' does not appear to be a git repository, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: That basically means your remote path is wrong. It found no repository at the path you set.