# Specifying port in ls-remote

Tags: git

Anyone know how I'd specify a non standard port in this code?

```
git ls-remote git@git:2222:common/jenkins-libraries.git
```

Our git server is running on a non standard port, 2222, so I need to get the port into that command somehow.

Comment: Try `git ls-remote git@${host}:2222/common/jenkins-libraries.git`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh+port+url

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738592/7976758. So you cannot set port in scp-like URL. Rewrite it with `ssh://` protocol: `git ls-remote ssh://git@git:2222/common/jenkins-libraries.git`.

Comment: Thanks all.  I created a .ssh/config file in the end and put the port and some other details in there.